# Importing LinkedList in Java giving an error

Tags: java, import, linked-list

I have created a class called 'Function' and want to create a LinkedList in it. So I have written the following code (Cropped to the problem area only).

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Function{
     ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     LinkedList<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    protected void addbeg(){


    }
}
```

In the import LinkedList line, I am getting the following error: "The `import java.util.LinkedList` conflicts with a type defined in the same file"

and In the line where I declaring a variable linkedList of type Linked list `LinkedList<Integer> linkedlist = new LinkedList<Integer>()`, it is giving the follwoing error 'The type LinkedList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments '

Any help how to eliminate these error? I have seen some tutorial on Java LinkedList where they have written same code without getting any error. I should also mention that The ArrayList is running without any error.

Comment: The problem is probably in other part of the code that you didn't show. If you put the code you have provided in a seperate file it will compile just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The import java.util.LinkedList conflicts with a type defined in the same file

The error is really quite specific, it's saying that somewhere in the file you have:

```
class LinkedList {
}
```

...or possibly `interface LinkedList` or `enum LinkedList`, though that latter seems unlikely.

Remove or rename that, or remove the `import` use the fully-qualified name when using `java.util.LinkedList` (**strongly** recommend the former, not the latter).

Comment: Thanks That helps a lot. Actually I made another class with the name 'LinkedList', renaming that solved the problem. Thanks again. Have a great day.